Using SPI and GPIO in Pi OS Bookworm on Pi 3b v1.2
How can I control GPIO from the CLI when I have SPI enabled?
I need to add a reset signal to an application that issues the reset via a shell script, prior to launching the application.  The application is LoRa Basic Station with IC880A.
echo '#!/bin/bash

# Reset iC880a PIN
SX1301_RESET_BCM_PIN=25
echo "$SX1301_RESET_BCM_PIN"  > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$SX1301_RESET_BCM_PIN/direction
echo "0"   > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$SX1301_RESET_BCM_PIN/value
sleep 0.1
echo "1"   > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$SX1301_RESET_BCM_PIN/value
sleep 0.1
echo "0"   > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$SX1301_RESET_BCM_PIN/value
sleep 0.1
echo "$SX1301_RESET_BCM_PIN"  > /sys/class/gpio/unexport

# Test the connection, wait if needed.
while [[ $(ping -c1 google.com 2>&1 | grep " 0% packet loss") == "" ]]; do
echo "[TTN Gateway]: Waiting for internet connection..."
sleep 30
done

# Start station
/opt/ttn-station/bin/station
' | sudo tee /opt/ttn-station/bin/start.sh

What changes should I make to the above script to make it work with Pi OS Bookworm?

Frankly the script is poor practice. It would make more sense to configure your system to wait for network before booting. There seems to be no reason to write a system script which requires root access.

The Sysfs GPIO interface has been deprecated for years and has FINALLY been removed!
There must be hundreds of posts on this site discussing this topic.
The official method is to install gpiod which has command line tools but there are other tools.
E.g. the gpioinfo command can be used to list all pins, and identify those in use. See libgpiod

It is difficult to understand why you think SPI has anything to do with state of GPIO pins.
